# Kafka Streams Application with Background Thread

Tags: multithreading, scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We are developing a Kafka Stream application in Scala that reads a request from a Kafka topic, processes the request, and writes the response to a Sink Kafka topic.

```
  def transformRecords(inputTopic: String, outputTopic: String): Topology = {
    val builder: StreamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder()
    builder.
      stream[String,RequestSchema](inputTopic)
      .map(transformToResponseSchema)
      .to(outputTopic)

    builder.build()
  }
```

To be able to use transformToResponseSchema, we have an in-memory map of key->value that needs to be updated in a scheduled way from a third party API in order to be able to process and transform the request to a response.

Is there any in-house solution we can use other than having a background thread that runs in a scheduled way and updates the map accordingly?

Comment: It seems like a classic use case of cache to me. You can checkout guava caches https://www.baeldung.com/guava-cache

Comment: @RishabhSharma I think you did not understand the use case here, I must to update my dictionary by going to another third party API.

Comment: As per my understanding - you want to transform your request data to response data using in memory map which would be updated periodically. Now this is memory map to me is a cache which gets updated from some source like db or api. Please let me know where is the disconnect.

Comment: You can have a timer generate "tick" messages at certain intervals, and when your job receives that special message, it updates the metadata. Technically, it's still a background thread (at least, if you use one of the default java schedulers), but only one for the entire app, and fairly light-weight (just send a message to topic and quit). Alternatively, just keep the timestamp of last update with your data, and when it gets old, simply refresh it.

Comment: @Dima very interesting idea about the special message, so in any how, the alternative is to have a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

> must update my dictionary by going to another third party API

A Guava `CacheLoader` + `LoadingCache` can do that. When you call to "get" the key, then a background function will be executed to fetch the data you want to load into the cache.

The alternative solution is to "export" your 3rd party data into a Kafka topic, which can be built into a KTable, and joined against all within Kafka Streams API.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I wrote for one of my jobs (hope, they will not sue me for disseminating such a brilliant piece of corporate know-how :) ):

```
class RefreshingValue[T](frequency: FiniteDuration)(refresh: => T) extends Function0[T] {
    lazy val cache = new ThreadLocal[(T, Deadline)] {
      override def initialValue() = (refresh, Deadline.now + frequency)
    }

    def apply() = cache.get match {
      case (_, deadline) if deadline.isOverdue =>
        cache.set(refresh, Deadline.now + frequency)
        cache.get._1
      case (v, _) => v
    }
 }
```

The way you use it is something like this:

```
val mappings = new RefreshingValue(30 minutes)(refreshMappingsFromAPI)
```

And then, when you need to use it, you just use `mappings()` to get the current value or to refresh it if it is stale.
This does not need any background threads or third-party libraries.

Comment: thanks for posting.

I tried the following 

val mappings = new RefreshingValue(Duration(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS))(refreshMappingsFromAPI())


def refreshMappingsFromAPI() = {
  Map("key1"->2, "key2" -> 3)
}


and when trying to run it, getting the following exception 

expected class or object definition
def refreshMappingsFromAPI() = {

any ideas about what missing here?

Comment: Looks like you have a syntax error somewhere :/

Comment: [works for me](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/4g7Y2vJGQQaeY8nhAopTWQ)